# Method show Exception when extract a substring from a string in android

Tags: java, android, exception, substring

I tried to convert `String` of *UTC date* to `String` of *Current Date* using method attached below.

Method throws `Index out of bound Exception` in mentioned line.

[image]

Comment: error is self explaining everything...what is your confusion?

Comment: Lokesh Desai , how to handle this Issue

Comment: There is no brackets in your string so it will return index as -1 .If you are playing with date use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calender`. Do not use `subString`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `(` character in your `utcDate` so `indexOf()` will return -1. Then you `substring()` from 0 index to -1 index. But the minimum index of character array inside String is 0. So it caused `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

See: [String#substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)). In the document it says throws
`IndexOutOfBoundsException` if beginIndex is larger than endIndex.